# How to use OR task condition in azure devops using parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, conditional-statements

```
parameters:
- name: agents
  displayName: Agent
  type: string
  default: test111
- name: tests
  displayName: “Hello test”
  type: string
  default:
    '"Hello World"'
- name: configuration_key
  displayName: Special Parameter Keyword
  type: string
  default: ""

jobs:
- job: tesst1
  strategy:
    matrix: ${{ parameters.execution_matrix }}
  variables:
    - name: 'TEST_S'
      value: ${{ parameters.tests }}
    - name: 'configuration_key'
      value: ${{ parameters.configuration_key }}
      displayName: App test
  timeoutInMinutes: 600
  pool:
    name: System_test
    
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      source: 'specific'
      project: ‘Test APP’
      buildType: 'current'
      artifactName: ‘App Installer'
      pipeline: 001
      runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'
      runBranch: 'refs/heads/develop'
      targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/'
    displayName: 'Get Artifacts'
    condition: or( eq(‘{{parameters.agents}}', ‘test111’), eq(‘{{parameters.agents}}’, ‘test’222) )
```

Added the complete code. Default value will be test111. Just need to verify the condition and execute the tasks.

```
  Note: If i use only one condition then its working like below.
  
  eq('$ {{parameters.agents}}', 'test111')
```

Either of any one agent is matched, then condition should be allow to execute tasks.

Comment: Could you try `condition: or( eq(parameters.agents, 'test111'), eq(parameters.agents, 'test222') )`

Comment: ##[error]Unrecognized value: 'parameters'. Located at position 8 within expression:
Getting this error. @GeralexGR

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work. As parameters are populated before the compile time, you should assign this value into a variable in order to use it on the condition step.

```
trigger:
- none

pr: none 

    parameters:
    - name: image
      displayName: Pool Image
      type: string
      default: ubuntu-latest
      values:
      - windows-latest
      - ubuntu-latest
      - macOS-latest
    
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    
    variables:
    - name: myvar
      value: ${{ parameters.image}}
    steps:
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          
          Write-Host "Hello World"
      condition: or( eq(variables.myvar, 'ubuntu-latest'), eq(variables.myvar, 'windows-latest') )
```

As the default value is evaluated correctly on the condition, the `powershell` will run.

[image]

Comment: Same error am getting.

Comment: Can you adjust your code from my provided example? As you can see, the example works as needed.

Comment: Added the complete code. please check and help. @GerlexGR

Comment: I noted multiple error on your `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task. Indentation seems to be problematic.  Also some attributes seem incorrect. For example `buildType: 'specific'` is the correct and not `source 'specific'` Try to check the documentation to resolve issues. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops

Comment: With AND operation its working perfectly fine but only for OR condition my code is not working. I am doing matrix calculus and all attributes are are correct. While copy and paste indentation missed may be.

Comment: parameter mapping to variables works perfekt, even inside Templates, thx for this answer